# How do I perform the atan2 function in T-SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, math, atan2

I need to execute the ATAN2 function in MS SQL Server. How do I do this?

T-SQL appears to have all the usual math functions like cos, sin, radians etc, just not ATAN2. What is the function for this?

Knowing how to do this in MySQL would be very useful as well, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, it's ATN2.

Dang.

Sorry folks.

Comment: I can mark it as answered in 2 days, according to the lightbox. I will do it then, as I'm sure this will be useful to someone. Like me, in the future. D'oh!

Comment: Useful list of MS SQL T-SQL built in maths functions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: That's the stupidest thing I've ever seen.  Why take out that A?

Comment: @duffymo I'm sure it was [inherited from the days of Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks111.htm). Only difference is, even [Sybase was smart enough to rename it](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Atan2.htm).

Comment: NO surprise - Microsoft stole Sybase during a partnering exercise.

Comment: This is definitely useful! It saved me some trouble at least.